how can i store the output of if-else conditions in an array in Java Swing and accessing it in different JFrames
I'm working on a Java Swing application where I need to store the output of if-else conditions in an array and then call this stored array in a different JFrame.
here is the sample code that im working
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
       ArrayList<Gradeprac> studList = Gradeprac.getStudentList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblStudents.getModel();
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0, row = 0; i < studList.size(); i++) 
        if (studList.get(i).section.equals(cmbSections.getSelectedItem().toString())) 
            Object value = model.getValueAt(row, 2);

            if (value == null || ((String) value).isEmpty()) 
                value = "NE";
                model.setValueAt(value, row, 2);
 
            String grade = convertToGrade(value);

            System.out.println("Percentage: " + value + "% - Grade: " + grade);

            row++;
  
private String convertToGrade(Object value) 
    try 
        double percentage = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
        int percentageInt = (int) percentage;

        if (percentageInt < 100 && percentageInt >= 96.5) 
            return "1.00";
         else if (percentageInt < 97 && percentageInt >= 92.5) 
            return "1.25";
         else if (percentageInt < 93 && percentageInt >= 88.5) 
            return "1.50";
         else if (percentageInt < 89 && percentageInt >= 84.5) 
            return "1.75";
         else if (percentageInt < 85 && percentageInt >= 81.5) 
            return "2.00";
         else if (percentageInt < 82 && percentageInt >= 78.5) 
            return "2.25";
         else if (percentageInt < 79 && percentageInt >= 75.5) 
            return "2.50";
         else if (percentageInt < 76 && percentageInt >= 72.5) 
            return "2.75";
         else if (percentageInt < 73 && percentageInt >= 69.5) 
            return "3.00";
         else if (percentageInt < 70 && percentageInt >= 0) 
            return "5.00";
        else 
            return "INC";
        
     catch (NumberFormatException e) 
        return "NE";
         

thank you

Not enough code is presented here to understand what you are doing wrong.
A little more of the code along with the exact error / output you are seeing will help.

You should clarify your problem, because it's unclear, what do you want to to is probably wrong.

i just need to modify my code to store the output of if else statement to an array then how to call the stored array in different jframe. thank you

If you would like to access variables in multiple JFrames, you should create public static variables which can be accessed in different JFrames.
I assume that you want to create an array of all the grade Strings which is then accessible in another JFrame. If so you should create a new public static ArrayList<String> and .add() all the grades to it. So your new code would look like this:
public class yourFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    // insert this line:
    public static ArrayList<String> grades = new ArrayList();
    ...
    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        ArrayList<Gradeprac> studList = Gradeprac.getStudentList();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblStudents.getModel();
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();

        for (int i = 0, row = 0; i < studList.size(); i++) {
            if (studList.get(i).section.equals(cmbSections.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
            Object value = model.getValueAt(row, 2);

            if (value == null || ((String) value).isEmpty()) {
                value = "NE";
                model.setValueAt(value, row, 2);
            }
            String grade = convertToGrade(value);
            // add each grade to your array
            grades.add(grade);
        }
        row++;
    }
    ...
}

Then if you want to access this array in another JFrame you can import it into the JFrame using import static package.yourFrame.grades then it can be accessed in that JFrame by its name grades.
Alternatively you can just refer to it by package.yourFrame.grades.
